# Highcharts bar chart highlight min and max y value/bar

Tags: highcharts, tags, highlight

I'm looking for a way to display the min and max value within a basic bar chart. I'm able to find min/max by getExtremes(). However, how to highlight them within the chart?

```
// Max Value
chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().dataMax
```

An extra would be, if I resize the selection, the min/max should be altered.
My approach is something like this:

```
var min = chart.series[0].dataMin;
var max = chart.series[0].dataMax;

for (var i = 0; i < chart.series[0].points.length; i++) {
    if (chart.series[0].points[i].y === max) {
        chart.series[0].points[i].update({color: 'red'});
    }
    if (chart.series[0].points[i].y === min) {
        chart.series[0].points[i].update({color: 'yellow'});
    }
}
```

However, this approach is very slow... :-(

//EDIT: Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/wiesson/3V398

Comment: What do you mean "highlight them"?

Comment: I thought, to redraw them in another color, or add something that the user will immediately know, okay this is the max/min value.

Comment: You need to find correct point, not value to highlight that point. After you have that point, simply call `point.update({ color: 'red' });` to highlight it. Of course you need to de-highlight previous points.

Comment: Looks fine to me. How to select the Point? There must be a faster way than iterating the chart.series[0].data array and match the y value with the max value?

Comment: `approach is very slow`, how are you measuring this?  Do you have thousands of datapoints?

Comment: It's simple `for()`. Highcharts doesn't store min/max point.

Comment: Even if simple for may not affect performance, updating point by `point.update()`may not be the best possible option. As workaround I suggest to use renderer to draw some shapes in that point places, simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p0tcjgqg/2/

Comment: Looks good very good to me, however I'm using Highcharts instead of Highstocks. Any workaround here? Or is this the same?